# How to use .on('child_added') to return all children?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, I want to use .on('child_added') to return all children rather than returning just one children. I want all children after every child_added, so .once('value') is not an option.
How to achieve this ?

For eg. In my database I have,
[book1, book2, book3] as children. When I add a new child book4, the .on('child_added') returns only {book4}. I want it to return [book1,book2,book3,book4]
Help me with this.

Comment: "*I want all children after every child_added*" - I'm not clear what this means.  It would be helpful if you edit the question to provide a specific example.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question and also gave an example. In docs it states that .on('child_added') returns only one child, but I want the complete array.

Comment: It sounds like you do want once("value").  Why is it not an option?

Comment: Because I want to trigger it after child is added

Comment: That's precisely what once("value") will do. Have you tried it?  If so, show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what it's doing differently.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say "on('value')".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on('value')](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#value-event) to receive updates to any child under a node.  Any time anything changes under that node, it will receive a snapshot of all nested children.